# Definition of the Authagraph projection

Tags: coordinate-system, cartography, globe

I recently came across this new map projection, the [Authagraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authagraph_projection). It seems pretty interesting and I'd like to play around with it, but I can't seem to find the math for projecting it, short of deriving it from scratch.

Is the math behind the Authagraph documented anywhere online?

Answer (score 4):

The original implementation by Hajime Narukawa is closed source, so we're not exactly sure how it is drawn.

[**Here**](https://marcinciura.wordpress.com/2016/11/20/authagraph/) is an open source implementation of a "pseudo-Authagraph" by Marcin Ciura, which is approximate to the original:
[image]

See [C source code](https://bitbucket.org/mciura/pseudo-authagraph/src) for implementation with PROJ.4. (NB. The original link is broken, an archived version is available [here](https://bitbucket-archive.softwareheritage.org/projects/mc/mciura/pseudo-authagraph.html).)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the one mentioned by Mike T, There is another open source approximation (which I believe is closer to the original) by Justin Haruaki Kunimune described and made available on [his blog](https://kunimune.home.blog/2017/11/23/the-secrets-of-the-authagraph-revealed/) with code available on [github](https://github.com/jkunimune15/Map-Projections).

[image: Comparison between Kunimune's version (black line) and the original (green)]

Comparison between Kunimune's version (black line) and the original (green)